# Jquery place an object elsewhere on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place an image into another div on hover.

Something like:

```
// I want to place this particular instance of .source into .place-here
$('.source').hover(function() {
    $('.place-here').append(this);
});
```

Although this does not work.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkasunzz/) if you are interested in helping me..

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Load the jQuery library in the left panel and it will work.

Comment: This is working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dkasunzz/1/

Comment: not really relevant, but kinda curious, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the hover method of jQuery correctly. The method expects two parameters, a function to be called onmouseover, and another to be called onmouseout.

To append the item to the .place-here div, you need to clone it first. Otherwise the .source div would be moved to the .place-here div and the onmouseout function would be called instantly. I've updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/donnellyjoe/dkasunzz/2/

```
// on hover add the image to the preview area
$('.source').hover(onOver, onOut);

function onOver(){
    var clone = $('.source').clone();
    $('.place-here').append(clone);
}

function onOut(){
    $('.place-here').empty();
}
```

Comment: You can also [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the element and then append it, but I think cloning it makes more sense.